# How do I import package/module from a directory above

Tags: python, cron, anaconda, jupyter, python-import

```
MyFolder/
        function_folder/
                    __init__.py
                    function.py
                          def some_func():
                              return 'i am func'
                    creds.py
                          class creds(elf)
                               self.user=[]
                               self.pw=[]
        test_folder/
                    test.py
        prod_folder/
                    live.py
```

We're trying to organize the folders such that we separate a folder for python functions and testing scripts and live scripts for automation.

How do you import `function.py` from `live.py`?

i've tried the following but none seem to work.

```
from .function import some_func
from ..function import some_func
from function_folder.function import *
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond top-level package or function_folder is not a module
```

Comment: from .. import  function_folder.function this will resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path_to_MyFolder/function_folder')
import function
```